# Writing HTTP responses to a temporary bytes.Buffer

Tags: go

I've been doing some profiling and benchmarking in order to optimise writing out to a temporary `bytes.Buffer` to catch any errors from `template.ExecuteTemplate`.

Specifically, we're writing to the buffer, checking for any errors, and if none, writing out to our `http.ResponseWriter`. The problem, however, is that the temporary buffer has a request overhead that's somewhat noticeable:

- About 6.2k req/s - 27.6k -> 21.4k with profiling on, and 29k -> 24k with it off;
- A 9ms (40ms -> 49ms) increase in per request latency.

Of course, 21k req/s is still a lot of requests, but a 22% perf. hit is also a fairly large impact.

```
func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, name string, data map[string]interface{}) error {
    // Ensure the template exists in the map.
    tmpl, ok := templates[name]
    if !ok {
        return ErrTemplateDoesNotExist
    }

    // Create a buffer to temporarily write to and check if any errors were encountered.
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, 10000))
    err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(buf, "base", data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Set the header and write the buffer to the http.ResponseWriter
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
        buf.WriteTo(w)

    return nil
}
```

The 10K buffer size is a rough estimation of the typical max page size of *most* of my responses, although I've yet to test this beyond a small handful of pages just yet. A response larger than the buffer size typically results in another 20% hit to performance.

**Is there a better way to write to a temporary buffer in *every* request?** Another gopher pointed out the upcoming [sync.Pool](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/sync/) in Go 1.3, but I'm not sure where to start when it comes to writing that out.

---

**Added**: using http://godoc.org/github.com/oxtoacart/bpool at the moment yields 33k req/s at 36ms per request:

```
var bufpool *bpool.BufferPool

func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, name string, data map[string]interface{}) error {
    ...
    buf := bufpool.Get()
    err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(buf, "base", data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Set the header and write the buffer to the http.ResponseWriter
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
    buf.WriteTo(w)
    bufpool.Put(buf)

    return nil
}

func init() {
    bufpool = bpool.NewBufferPool(48)

}
```

Comment: Why not implement a simple pool for buffers? Just a simple FIFO or something?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Are you able to provide an example snippet? play.golang.org is fine - just need to understand the approach.

Comment: this looks like it will work (search godoc a bit for a few other alternatives): http://godoc.org/github.com/oxtoacart/bpool

Comment: you should probably also see an increase in throughput regardless of size, just by reducing the garbage collector pressure.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer That's looking very positive (as per update to my Q) - better than the example that *doesn't* write to a temporary buffer. Feel free to copy+paste your comment into an answer.

Comment: Also - just to further my understanding - what would be the reason for the pool implementation beating the 'naked'—no buffer - just a direct write to the ResponseWriter—approach?

Comment: probably less garbage collection going on. but I'm not sure :)

Comment: Why 48? What is that magical?

Comment: @kristen Some benchmarking showed that worked for my use case, and kept total memory size down (48 * buffer size baseline). sync.Pool can make this dynamic but discards unused buffers during GC cycles, so spiky traffic can be disadvantageous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[copied from comments as an answer]

Just pool your buffers using an available pool not from the standard library. This one looks like it will work (search godoc a bit for a few other alternatives):

http://godoc.org/github.com/oxtoacart/bpool

Yyou should probably also see an increase in throughput regardless of size, just by reducing the garbage collector pressure.

Comment: http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#leaky_buffer "in which case the buffer is dropped on the floor" -- oddly specific about where to drop the buffer.